# What's the difference between express-session and cookie-session?

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies

I am new with *Express*. As *Express 4.x* has removed bundled middlewares.

Any middleware I want to use should be required. When I read the README with [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) and [cookie-session](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) on github, I find it hard to understand the difference.

I tried to write some simple code to figure it out. I ran it twice for each middleware.

```js
var express = require('express')
  , cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
  , session = require('cookie-session')
  , express_sess = require('express-session')
  , app = express();

app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(session({ keys: ['abc'], name: 'user' }));
//app.use(express_sess({ secret: 'abc', key: 'user'}));
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.end(JSON.stringify(req.cookies));
    console.log(req.session)
    console.log(req.cookies)
});

app.listen(3000);
```

For `cookie-session`, I always get `{}` in my terminal.

For `express-session`, I get things like this.

```js
req.session: { cookie: { 
     path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true 
   } 
}

req.cookie: {user: 's:aJ97vKA5CCwxqdTj0AV1siRQ.fWusS5+qfCKICtwkfrzcZ/Gq8P0Qdx/kx8mTBhoOhGU'}
```

It really confuses me. So how to explain the result with the basic use? And what's the difference between them? When should I use them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between 'session' and 'cookieSession' middleware in Connect/Express?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744897/what-is-the-difference-between-session-and-cookiesession-middleware-in-conne)

Answer (score 56):

Basically, `express-session` is more abstract, it supports different session stores (like files, DB, cache and whatnot).

And `cookie-session` is a simple / lightweight cookie-based (cookie is the only storage engine supported: all the session info is stored on the client, in a cookie) session implementation. This kind of sessions is probably most famous for its [Rails implementation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session).

Comment: is there a good place where I can read about the advantages/disadvantages of client-only vs server-side cookies/sessions? for someone who knows nothing, it's hard to know where to start on this

Comment: @AlexMills The link to the Rails guide in the answer pretty much explains it.

Answer (score 25):

The basic difference between both these relates to how and where is the session data being stored. 
**Cookie session** is basically used for lightweight session applications where the session data is stored in a cookie but within the *client [browser]*, whereas, **Express Session** stores just a mere session identifier within a cookie in the client end, whilst storing the session data entirely on the server. 
**Cookie Session** is helpful in applications where no database is used in the back-end. However, the session data cannot exceed the cookie size. On conditions where a database is used, it acts like a cache to stop frequent database lookups which is expensive.

Answer (score 10):

`express-session` stores the session identifier in the cookie while the actual session data resides in backend session store like `connect-redis`, where as `cookie-session` allows you to store the session data in a cookie (client-side).

From the documentation of `cookie-session`:

> A user session can be stored in two main ways with cookies: on the
>   server or on the client. This module stores the session data on the
>   client within a cookie, while a module like express-session stores
>   only a session identifier on the client within a cookie and stores the
>   session data on the server, typically in a database.

The main advantage of using `cookie-session` is when you have a clustered `node.js` app, then you don't have to rely on sharing session data between forked processes.

Comment: That is true about the clustering part and its  big plus so what about security side of things

Answer (score 8):

Let me share an important difference I found: **secure cookies**.

I have a node process behind an nginx proxy which handles SSL.

I tried with express-session, but I could not enable secure cookies, see [issue here](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/281#issuecomment-191283280).

Then I tried with almost the same code, but with *cookie-session* instead, something like

```
   const expressSession = require('cookie-session')

   var expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 7 days

    const session = expressSession({
      secret: sessionSecret,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      cookie: {
        secureProxy: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        domain: 'example.com',
        expires: expiryDate
      }
    })

    app.use(session)
```

I just changed `require('express-session')` to `require('cookie-session')` and added `secureProxy: true,`: everything worked out of the box.

Note also that both packages are maintained by [expressjs](https://github.com/expressjs) so probably in my use case I was lucky finding out that cookie-session fits my needs.

Comment: Note that this was caused by a misconfigured reverse proxy in front of express (`X-Forwarded-Proto` was missing). Secure cookies are fully supported by `express-session` as well.

Comment: I'm not sure that this post is right - most of the configuration below 'const session=....' is specific to express-session and incompatible with cookie-session.  Coding as above just throws error messages.

Answer (score 8):

The official Express.js [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html#use-cookies-securely) refers to

> The main difference between these two modules is how they save cookie session data.
>
> The `express-session` middleware stores session data on the server; it only saves the session ID in the cookie itself, not session data. By default, it uses in-memory storage and is not designed for a production environment. In production, you’ll need to set up a scalable session-store; see the list of compatible session stores.
>
> In contrast, `cookie-session` middleware implements cookie-backed storage: it serializes the entire session to the cookie, rather than just a session key. Only use it when session data is relatively small and easily encoded as primitive values (rather than objects). Although browsers are supposed to support at least 4096 bytes per cookie, to ensure you don’t exceed the limit, don’t exceed a size of 4093 bytes per domain. Also, be aware that the cookie data will be visible to the client, so if there is any reason to keep it secure or obscure, then `express-session` may be a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

The get a non-empty console.log(req.session) you need to set session values before logging.

From the cookie-session repo (https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session):

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
 req.session.views = (req.session.views || 0) + 1
 console.log(req.session)
 res.end(req.session.views + ' views')
})
```

If you never set any info on the req.session object, it will return empty.

Answer (score 2):

### **Here is a simple explanation: -**

A **user session** can be stored in two main ways with cookies: **on the server** or **on the client**.

- **express-session** stores only a session identifier on the client within a cookie and stores the session data on the server, typically in a database.
- **cookie-session** stores the session data on the client within a cookie

Comment: Can't session data stored on the client be changed by the user?

Comment: @parsecer cookies are cryptographically signed by cookie-session which prevents tampering with the contents of the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

v4-> cookie-session is (Establish cookie-based sessions.)   equals in ->v3 express.cookieSession

v4-> express-session is (Establish server-based sessions (development only)).   equals in ->v3 express.session

Answer (score 0):

`express-session` stores session data into configurable backends, ranging from memory to any number of databases, thus allowing essentially unlimited session storage.

`cookie-session` stores session data into cookies, thus being limited to a bit under 4k bytes of session storage.

Most of the rest of the differences are consequences of this decision:

`cookie-session` works without depending on an external datastore (so less infrastructure to set up, configure, maintain).
`cookie-session` works behind load balancers without 'sticky-sessions' having to be enabled/configured.